# How can I dynamically get the value of a class variable?

Tags: python

I am using a framework that has a class similar to this:

```
class foo:
    bar = 1
    baz = 2
```

And I then have an input variable containing a string equal to the name of one of these class variables. I know for a dictionary, you can do dict[variable] to dynamically decide the field you want; is there a similar syntax for getting a class variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any object, you can use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr).  In your case, you apply it to the *class object*, because `bar` is a member of the class object.

```
attr = 'bar'
getattr(foo, attr)  # <=> foo.bar
```